# How to store key, value pair in dictionary from file?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

I have an input.txt file like below format.

```py
     A             = Xyz 
     B 
      Value:274:53:3
     C             = 1190
     E
       WQQQW 
        Value:554
     A             = UrR 
     B 
      Value:113:00:1
     C             = 34 
     E
       WQQQW 
        Value:982
```

I'd like to store in a dictionary the data related with A, B and E in order to get:

```py
d = {
        'A': ['Xyz', 'UrR'],
        'B': ['274:53:3', '113:00:1'],
        'E': ['554', '982'],
    }
```

I'm doing like below, not I only storing the key, value pair related with `A` since the values for `A` are in the same line.

```py
d = {"A":[],"B":[],"E":[]}

for line in open('input.txt'):
    lst_line = line.replace(":", "=", 1).split("=")
    if ("A" or "B" or "E") in lst_line[0]:
        k = lst_line[0].strip()
        v = lst_line[1].replace("\n", "").strip()
        d[k].append(v)
    
>>> d
{'A': ['Xyz', 'UrR'], 'B': [], 'E': []}
```

I'm stuck in how to store the values for `B` that is one line below after `Value:` and for `E` that is 2 lines below after `Value:`.

Answer (score 1):

Every key seems to have a very specific logic which can be divided into independent `if` conditions. Below code reads value for respective key based on the condition mentioned in question.

```
d = {"A": [], "B": [], "E": []}

with open("input.txt") as file:
    while True:
        line = file.readline()  # read next line
        if not line:
            break  # break on end of file

        lst_line = line.replace(":", "=", 1).split("=")  # key from line

        if "A" in lst_line[0]:
            k = lst_line[0].strip()
            v = lst_line[1].replace("\n", "").strip()
            d[k].append(v)

        if "B" in lst_line[0]:
            k = lst_line[0].strip()
            line = file.readline()  # read next line for value i.e. if key is B value is on the next line (one line below)
            lst_line = line.replace(":", "=", 1).split("=")  # get value for B
            v = lst_line[1].replace("\n", "").strip()
            d[k].append(v)

        if "E" in lst_line[0]:
            k = lst_line[0].strip()
            file.readline()  # skip junk line
            line = file.readline()  # read next line for value i.e. for E value is two lines below.
            lst_line = line.replace(":", "=", 1).split("=")  # get value for E
            v = lst_line[1].replace("\n", "").strip()
            d[k].append(v)

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
 {'A': ['Xyz', 'UrR'], 'B': ['274:53:3', '113:00:1'], 'E': ['554', '982']}
```

Comment: you can also show the output of the statement `print(d)`

Comment: sure, added output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use regex:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as r:
    r = r.read()

dct = {'A': re.findall('(?<=A             \= ).*?(?= \n)',r),
       'B': re.findall('\d\d\d:\d\d:\d',r),
       'E': re.findall('(?<=Value:)\d\d\d(?!:)',r)}

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['Xyz', 'UrR'],
 'B': ['274:53:3', '113:00:1'],
 'E': ['554', '982']}
```